# Of Countries and their Cities

Tags: database, countries

I need a database of Countries and their Cities.

Any idea where I can get such a list?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There are quite a few available.

The following has database for 2,401,039 cities

http://www.geodatasource.com/world-cities-database/free

Comment: thanks a lot :D its not an over kill :D

Comment: Is there anyway to know the state/province related to the city with this?

Comment: Actually there is not only cities but it was very helpful, thanks.

Comment: Here is the [updated link](http://www.geodatasource.com/world-cities-database/free)

Comment: If you are looking for just the SQL for Country table and all the countries this would help: http://www.infomazing.net/blog/database-country-table-with-sql-insert-statements

Answer (score 40):

From all my searching around, I strongly say that the most practical, accurate and free data source is provided by [GeoNames](http://geonames.org/).

You can access their data in 2 ways:

1. The easy way through their free web services.
2. Import their free text files into Database tables and use the data in any way you wish. This method offers much greater flexibility and have found that this method is better.

Comment: Only problem with them is that their country list is 2 characters long for each country.  Not really optimal unfortunately

Comment: If you are looking for list of Country table with insert for all the countries there is a single sql script here :http://www.infomazing.net/blog/database-country-table-with-sql-insert-statements

Comment: Interesting database, but postal codes are not up to date for Italy (actually they are many years old)

Comment: @j.c Which one (GeoNames or informazing) contains errors in Italia ?

Comment: @devoh in some cities C.A.P. (codice avviamento postale) has changed many years ago, as an example 47522 was 47020, but old 47020 still works: http://www.geonames.org/postalcode-search.html?q=47020&country=IT while new 47521 doesn't.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know which one contains errors. In their defense, even Wikipedia shows the old post code. https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longiano I also check a shipping provider and 47020 gives Longiano as result ...

Comment: I have checked the Spanish cities, and it has a lot of mistakes and cities repeated...

Answer (score 19):

Go through this link http://www.maxmind.com/en/worldcities

It Includes the following fields:

1. Country Code
2. ASCII City Name
3. City Name
4. Region
5. Population
6. Latitude (The latitude and longitude are near the center of the most granular location value returned: postal code, city, region, or country)
7. Longitude

Comment: Is there an information about what the Region codes mean. These are mainly numbers, but sometimes they are not. (Perhaps they are Country abbreviation of the USA.)

Comment: Is there a mapping what county in a Country a number means?

Comment: Some modifications / cleanup to this data: https://github.com/JoshSmith/worldwide-city-database

Answer (score 10):

Check this out:

[Cities of the world database donated by MaxMind.com](http://drupal.org/node/19983)

*The company MaxMind.com[1](http://drupal.org/node/19983) has agreed to release their cities of the world database under the GPL. The database contains locations by country, city, latitude and longitude. There are over 3,047,000 records in the database. For those of you who have tried the location.module with the zipcodes database from CivicSpace, you will recognize how cool it is and how well this fits with that project and therefore Drupal.*

Here's [another free one](http://www.geonames.org/export/) that might help you get started.

Creating and maintaining such a database is quite a bit of work - so anyone who's done it is likely keeping it to themselves, or offering it for a fee.

Comment: thats neat. only problem is how to get around getting the country names into that. they just have abrev :(

Comment: Well, it's free and thus could be a starting point. Based on the abbrev., you should have no trouble finding the country names for those 200 countries or so and add them to your database table...

Comment: This project has cleaned up some of the issues with this data: https://github.com/JoshSmith/worldwide-city-database

Answer (score 9):

http://cldr.unicode.org/ - common standard multi-language database, includes country list and other localizable data.

Comment: Question about cities with global permanent ID and localized names is open :( I can't find solution. I plan maintain own application codelist with user contribution.

Answer (score 4):

https://code.google.com/p/worlddb/downloads/list

[Open World Database alpha](https://code.google.com/p/worlddb/downloads/list)

This database has multi languages country names, region names, city names and they's latitude and longitude number and country's alpha2 code .

Comment: i ended up using this one it is not an overkill like others with 3 million rows

Comment: Unable to find a lot of cities in Spain...

Answer (score 3):

United Nations list of locations in mdb, csv or txt:

Welcome:
http://www.unece.org/cefact/locode/welcome.html

[Choose the downloads link from the above link or just click here.](http://www.unece.org/cefact/codesfortrade/codes_index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use database from here -

http://myip.ms/info/cities_sql_database/

```
CREATE TABLE `cities` (
  `cityID` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cityName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `stateID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `countryID` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `language` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `latitude` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `longitude` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cityID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unq` (`countryID`,`stateID`,`cityID`),
  KEY `cityName` (`cityName`),
  KEY `stateID` (`stateID`),
  KEY `countryID` (`countryID`),
  KEY `latitude` (`latitude`),
  KEY `longitude` (`longitude`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was comparing worldcitiesdatabae.info with [www.worldcitiesdatabase.com](http://www.worldcitiesdatabase.com) and it appears the latter one to be more resourceful. However, maxmind has a free database so then why buy a cities database. Just get the free one and there is lot of help available on internet about maxmind db. If you put in extra efforts then you can save those few bucks :)

Answer (score 0):

This service returns Countries (name,code) and cities for any country as REST, SErvice. You can also download database and sample REST service

http://tecorange.com/content/world-countries-and-cities-restjson-service-12-months-subscription